# Upload Video in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I need a plugin for "Upload Videos" in a rails application.

Can anyone give me an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem, very popular for this purpose

Comment: Thanks. could you advice with a tutorial?

Answer (score 16):

You can also use `carrierwave` gem

- Add in your Gemfile: `gem 'carrierwave'`

  Run `bundle install`
- Create an uploader for uploading video using carrierwave generator.

  `rails g uploader video`
- It creates file `video_uploader.rb` in `uploaders` directory
- Create a migration in model where you want attach the video or image, be careful with the migration name it should be like `add_{column}_to_{model}`

  `rails g migration add_video_to_post video:string`
- Migrate database

  Run `rake db:migrate`
- Add uploader to the model

  ```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
        mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader  
  end
  ```
- Add video parameter in PostController

  ```
  class PostController < ApplicationController
        .
        . 
        .
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:name,:video)
        end
  end
  ```
- Add file attachment field in `_forml.html.erb` which is in `views/posts`

  ```
  <%=f.file_field :video%>
  ```
- To view/stream the video

  ```
  <% @posts.each do |post|%>
      <%= post.name %>
      <%= video_tag post.video_url.to_s :controls =>true %>
  <%end%>
  ```

for more information
carrierwave gem
  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave
and video tutorial
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: good solutions, working fine with carrierwave, I was thinking other solutions

Answer (score 6):

Even more specific, I created a Rails gem that works specifically with videos:
https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-ffmpeg