# Rails Carrierwave Video Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Im using carrierwave with my Rails 4 app.

I have two uploaders installed - one for avatar and one for video. I use both of them in my projects model.  My project.rb file has:

```
mount_uploader :hero_image, AvatarUploader
  mount_uploader :link_to_video_proposal, VideoUploader
```

My project controller includes:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:link_to_video_proposal)
```

My project _form has:

```
  <%=f.file_field :link_to_video_proposal%>
```

My project show page has:

```
     <%= video_tag @project.link_to_video_proposal_url.to_s :controls =>true %>
```

I have tried to follow the example in the 7 step answer in this post [Upload Video in a rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463572/upload-video-in-a-rails-application) (but changed the video tag from post.video to @project.link_to_video_proposal

When I save this and test it, I get an error that says:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (referring to the line in my show page).
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with adding if micropost.video?..

```
<%= video_tag micropost.video_url.to_s :controls =>true if micropost.video?%>
```